# Macro on argument not behaving as expected

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm trying to substitute a comma separated argument for a macro.

The code below works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    literate={->}{\texttt{->}}{2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    Example
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

As `\newcommand` simply generates a macro that will be substituted, I would expect the code below to work fine as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\somemacro}{{->}{\texttt{->}}{2}}

\lstset{
    literate=\somemacro
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    Example
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

However, it results in multiple errors.

So, where exactly am I wrong on my assumptions about `\newcommand` and how can I properly define a macro that can be used as an argument?

Comment: The `literate` setting expects 3 arguments and you've supplied one... even though that one contains 3 things. This is a common issue with expansion. Why not just include the three arguments verbatim for `literate`? Is there any reason for defining a macro that is only used in that single location?

Comment: @Werner Yeah. This MWE doen't make justice to the objective. The macro is exceptionally long, and it would basically "engulf" the other arguments in the code. It is not *necessary*, but it would increase code readability if it was isolated.

Comment: Would something like this work for you? `\newcommand{\somemacro}{literate={->}{\texttt{->}}{2}}
\expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\somemacro}`

Comment: @Werner This is more akin to what would actually be used: ...`{\#\{}{{\#\{}}2{\#[}{{\#[}}2{\#\#}{{\#\#}}2{\#\#\#}{{\#\#\#}}3{\#\#\#\#}{{\#\#\#\#}}4{\#(}{{\#(}}2{\#?}{{\#?}}2{\#_}{{\#\_}}2{\#_(}{{\#\_(}}3{.-}{{.-}}2{.=}{{.=}}2{..}{{..}}2{..<}{{..<}}3{...}{{...}}3{?=}{{?=}}2{??}{{??}}2`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to expansion as being an issue. Consider a similar example that is a little simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\someothermacro}[2]{.#1.#2.}
\newcommand{\someargument}{{first}{second}}

\begin{document}
\someothermacro\someargument
\end{document}
```

One would think that calling `\someothermacro\someargument` is similar to `\someothermacro{first}{second}`. Intuitively, yes, but TeX grabs arguments (tokens really) blindly. Since `\someothermacro` expects 2 arguments, it grabs `\someargument` as the first and `\end` (from `\end{document}` as the second, and then expands to `.{first}{second}.\end.` rather than `.first.second.`. Since `\end` doesn't have the appropriate environment name corresponding to its opening (`document` in this case) it fails, stating `\begin{document}` ended by `\end{.}`.

You can circumvent this using

```
\expandafter\someothermacro\someargument
```

which is fairly simple. However, in your setup, expansion has to occur different. More specifically, using a `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup ...}\x` is easiest.

If you want the style settings visible, you can use the following expanded form:

```
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\somemacro}{{->}{\noexpand\texttt{->}}{2}}

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand
\lstset{
  literate=\somemacro
}}\x
```

The "expansion code" surrounds your `\lstset` construction and requires any sensitive content (stuff that doesn't need to be expanded) to be prefixed with `\noexpand`.

It may be better to define a `style` using `\lstdefinestyle{<style>}{<key value list>}` where you can hide away some of the details, and then just use

```
\lstset{
  style=<style>,
  % other settings
}
```

in your main document.

Comment: Indeed, `\lstdefinestyle` is what is used on the package that implements what I wanted to implement (`lstfiracode`). My question was more "why that leads to an error", as my intuition told me it should work, and your comment clarified really well why it doesn't. So, if you add that explanation to your answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @LuizMartins: Done.